# Как заставить JS подождать 1 секунду перед выходом из функции?

Tags: javascript, время, sleep

Есть скрипт:

```
function func(){
    console.log('start');
    ...
}
func();
console.log('end');
```

Какой код написать вместо `...`, чтобы между первым логом и **выходом из функции** (а не между первым и вторым логом) прошла 1 секунда?

Если сделать так, то лог `time` выведется через секунду после лога `end`:

```
function func(){
    console.log('start');
    setTimeout(function(){console.log('time');}, 1000);
}
func();
console.log('end');
```

Comment: То, что вы хотите сделать, категорически не поощряется джаваскриптом. Лучше откажитесь от этого и изучите асинхронщину или хотя бы используйте этот самый setTimeout

Comment: @andreymal, я понимаю, может быть сделаю и без этого, но всё таки если как-то можно, лучше знать...

Comment: Вы хотите плохое, так что во имя всеобщего блага считайте что никак

Answer (score 5):

Это из разряда "Вредные советы": можете создать функцию `wait`, которая просто закупоривает JS.

```js
function wait(ms) {
  let current_date = Date.now();
  while (current_date + ms > Date.now()) {}
}

function func() {
  console.log('start');
  wait(1000); // 1000ms = 1s
}

func();
console.log('end');
```

(Сниппет выводит результат после окончания работы JS)

Я надеюсь, вы понимаете, что JS - однопоточный. Создавая такую ситуацию, вы, наверное, ломаете концепцию языка. Такого происходить не должно, вы не должны "замораживать" call stack.

А функция `setTimeout` относится к такому понятию как "Web Api". Эта функция позволяет отложить переданные инструкции на заданное время. Как только это время пройдёт, Web Api "вбросит" переданные инструкции в очередь, именуемую "call stack"

Comment: Именно поэтому я задал этот вопрос. :-)

Comment: чувствуете как в комнате потеплело?)